# Managing code responsibility separation on large mobile app

Tags: design, development-process, mobile, cross-platform

I work for a large corporation with some different business units.
Each of this business unities has their own group of developers.

We have to build a mobile app that has features from each of these business units. The app will have a initial screen where the user will choose the business unit he wants.

In web development, it's common to use iframes to separate the code repository and also the application infrastructure.

How could we manage to do this on **Android**, **iOS** and **Windows Phone**?

This app is going to have it's front-end developed in native code for each of these platforms.

In the perfect scenario we would have a single app and independent code repositories for each business unit, with no shared code, except for the initial screen.

For Android I thought of these undesirable alternatives:

1) One main app, and one for each business unit. The main app calls the other apps with an intent. This would give total code independence, but multiple apps on the store.

2) Single app with different business unit programmers developing on same code respository. This would give one app, but the code would be shared.

Comment: Will you have separate codebases for each platform or use something like Titanium/Xamarin/PhoneGap?

Comment: I'll have native code for each platform. But I'd like to learn how it's possible to do with a multi-platform framework too.

Comment: Will you be utilizing any API/Web Interfaces from any of the business units or will all the code/data in the mobile app be separate?

Comment: @JeffO, the common business code and database will be exposed by web services. But I'm worried just about the front-end mobile code.